# I am trying to use variable in select query with like clause but getting an error like invalid identifier

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to use variable in select query with like clause but getting an error like invalid identifier. Here is my method...

```
private void searchBooks(){

   try{
      String SEARCHFORTHIS=Find_Book_Field.getText();
      pst=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM BOOK WHERE NAME LIKE  '%'+ SEARCHFORTHIS +'%'");
      rs=pst.executeQuery();
      Show_All_Books.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
      }catch(SQLException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Oracle uses `||` instead of `+` for string concatenation.
`SELECT * FROM BOOK WHERE NAME LIKE  '%'||SEARCHFORTHIS||'%'` Plus you need to parametrize your query.

Comment: looks like quotes are missed , try this                                           conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM BOOK WHERE NAME LIKE  '%"+ SEARCHFORTHIS +"%'");

Comment: still getting same error by using this '%'||SEARCHFORTHIS||'%'

Answer (score 3):

NEVER use string concatenation to build a SQL statement with user-supplied text values.

Well, unless you really *want* your code to be susceptible to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, allowing a hacker to steal your data and delete your tables.

You're already using `PreparedStatement`, so use it right.

You should also use try-with-resources for correct resource management.

```
private void searchBooks() {
    String SEARCHFORTHIS = Find_Book_Field.getText();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM BOOK WHERE NAME LIKE ?";
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        stmt.setString(1, "%" + SEARCHFORTHIS + "%");
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            Show_All_Books.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
try{
  String SEARCHFORTHIS=Find_Book_Field.getText();
  pst=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM BOOK WHERE NAME LIKE  '%"+ SEARCHFORTHIS +"%'");
  rs=pst.executeQuery();
  Show_All_Books.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
  }catch(SQLException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
  }
}
```

Made changes in SELECT query only. you have not properly closed the double quote in it.

**Note**: 
completely agree with Andreas, we should use Preparedstatment, in this kind of scenarios, to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @RaviJha If I type `' AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM password_table WHERE user = 'bob' AND hash = '12345678' ) AND name LIKE '` into your `Find_Book_Field` then suddenly your query is checking what a user's password is instead of doing what you intend. Do **not** use string concatenation to build a query - use bind parameters.

Comment: Agree with this. we must use Preparedstatment, in this case, to prevent  SQL Injection attacks